# Regex to match "\t" and "\n" in the sentence :file_content, but I got the error like this

Tags: python, python-re

```
import re
re.search('\\n' | '\\t',file_content)
```

I got this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Try `'\\n|\\t'`. You cannot take bitwise-or of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

text = """
\tHi
There\t!
"""
pattern = re.compile(r'[\t\n]')  # Use compile to find all instances of the pattern
matches = pattern.finditer(text)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='\n'>
<re.Match object; span=(1, 2), match='\t'>
<re.Match object; span=(4, 5), match='\n'>
<re.Match object; span=(10, 11), match='\t'>
<re.Match object; span=(12, 13), match='\n'>
```

Using `[\t\n]` (a character set) is the most logical way to do it.

Comment: No problem! If this answered your question, please mark it as answered so others can see there are acceptable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to find \t\n through out the file content

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[\t\n]')
matches = pattern.findall(file_content)
print matches
```